# angular-aad-implicitflow

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, angularjs, adal

I see in SharePoint PnP Git repo: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples

There is `react-aad-implicitflow` why not there is `angular-aad-implicitflow`.

Is there any limitation having with angular. If any limitation then what it is? if no, is there any reference which I go through.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you can't use Angular with this type of app. The absence of a sample from the repo is just that no one has written it. You should be able to take the AAD specific code from the react sample and port it over to use Angualr.